# In Texworks, while the texts were aligned for the first couple of pages, it suddenly is no longer justified in alignment, and indention is not working

Tags: formatting, alignment, justification

Edit: When I try the paragraph in a new texfile without the front page, it is perfectly aligned. So it seems the problem could be in my cover page. I am adding the code and the error messages below-

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,  PhD]{muthesis}
\pagestyle{headings}
% Avoid some overfull boxes.
\emergencystretch=.1\hsize
\hbadness = 3000

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[perpage,para,symbol*]{footmisc}

\graphicspath{c:\MyFiles-Latex\Thesis-Figures}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  

\setpapersize{A4}
\setmarginsrb{40mm}{20mm}{25mm}{20mm}{10pt}{10mm}{10pt}{10mm}

%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand\verbatimtabsize{2\relax}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
\clubpenalty=9999 %theses two lines are
\widowpenalty=9999 
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand*{\Quote}[1]{\textquotedblleft#1\textquotedblright}

\def\Hanh{H\`an Th\^e\llap{\raise 0.5ex\hbox{\'{}}} Th\`anh}

\ifpdf
  \usepackage[%
    pdftex,%
    colorlinks,%
    hyperindex,%
    plainpages=false,%
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    a4paper,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=blue,
  ]{hyperref}
  %%?? \def\pdfBorderAttrs{/Border [0 0 0] } % No border arround Links
  \usepackage{thumbpdf}
\else
  \usepackage{hyperref}
\fi

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\thepage} 
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{}]
      {\fancyplain{}{}}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%  %Make the Chapter title in low case
%\markboth{\chaptername
%\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % This removes the line added by Fancy header

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Beginning of Document - First Page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
 \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{Monash's LOGO.png}}
\title {\huge {\textbf{Investigating the impact of flavonoid compounds on the cGAS-STING pathway}}}
\author {{\textbf{XXX}\\ Student ID: 6789976\\Jan 2018-December 2021}}
\date{}
\maketitle

A thesis submitted for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy \\at XXX University\\

Research was carried out\\in the ABCD\\ affiliated with XXX\\
Under the supervision of \\
A/Prof ASD (75\%)\\
and ASC(25\%)}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

**error message is below:**thesis Tom.tex

```
106 Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.106
thesis Tom.tex
110 LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.110 \newline
              {Research was carried out\\in XX ...
```

Comment: texworks is not involved, that is just the editor you used for writing the file. If the paragraph justification changes on some page that will be due to the latex commands you have on that page but you have not shown any code so it is hard to help.

Comment: Here is the command for that specific page>\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\markboth{Acknowledgements}{Acknowledgements}
text\\ 
&\\
text
&\\

Comment: No make a real example, in your question, not disconnected fragments, but your preamble generates the error `! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.28 \setpapersize
                  {A4}
? `   due to the line `\footnotetext` which should be removed.

Comment: `text\\ &\\ text &\\ `  ??? This is why you should not just post fragments, you can only use `&` in `tabular` and similar environments, is that fragment in a table, do you have `\chapter*` in a table??

Comment: Note if you have _any_ tex error the typeset output is not intended to be usable, just a possible debugging aid, and if you are asking about a document that makes errors show the exact error message from the log file in a code block so lines are preserved.

Comment: I omitted \footnotetext, but it still doesnot solve the issue.  I had text\\ for paragraph break, and used same thing in the page where the alignment is justified. I do have \chapter* in a table, yes.

Comment: The error messages are-"

Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<recently read> &
                 
l.176 &
       \\
thesis Tom.tex
176
LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.176 &\\
thesis Tom.tex
178
LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

"

Comment: yes as I say you can not have `&` except in a table it is the table cell separator. But as you see showing code and error messages in comments does not really work, you should add them to your question in code block so the lines can be seen. Start by removing the `&` and `\\ ` that generate errors before looking at the alignment in the output.

Comment: Neither of the errors you show is in any way related to the large amount of code you have shown, they are both due to the text you showed in the comment  `text\\ &\\ text &\\ ` which you should delete. If you want an `&` to appear in the output use `\&` not `&`

Comment: `\chapter*` in a `tabular` environment is very likely to break your code. You *can* align certain things with `tabular`s, but you should not (and cannot) align *everything* with `tabular`s. Also, you should not use `\\ ` to start a new paragraph, but instead the proper way is just to insert a blank line.

Comment: I added the code I used above with the question. As I mentioned, when I try the problematic paragraph in a separate Lyx window, it is aligned well. But When I have it with my first page/title page, it breaks. Something could be due to the error messages that I am getting? Though not sure how these relate?

Comment: If you get any tex error then if you get any typeset result at all then it's just by good luck and no point in worrying about alignment tex makes no attempt to make sensible output after an error it just recovers enough to try to syntax check more of the document

Comment: Maybe not related to the problem, but don't load the same package more than once, and don't load them at all unless you actually *need* them.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the preamble (are you definitely using latin-1 for example) but the main error is

```
\author {{\textbf{XXX}\\ Student ID: 6789976\\Jan 2018-December 2021}}
```

which should be

```
\author {\textbf{XXX}\\ Student ID: 6789976\\Jan 2018-December 2021}
```

without the extra brace group.

You should also remove `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` you do not want your title page to be in a float.

I am not sure what layout you want but if the built in `\maketitle` is not the design you want, you can use `titlepage` and set things by hand:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\def\MyFiles{?myfiles}
\def\Thesis{?thesis}
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,  PhD]{muthesis}
\pagestyle{headings}
% Avoid some overfull boxes.
\emergencystretch=.1\hsize
\hbadness = 3000

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[perpage,para,symbol*]{footmisc}

\graphicspath{c:\MyFiles-Latex\Thesis-Figures}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  

\setpapersize{A4}
\setmarginsrb{40mm}{20mm}{25mm}{20mm}{10pt}{10mm}{10pt}{10mm}

%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand\verbatimtabsize{2\relax}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
\clubpenalty=9999 %theses two lines are
\widowpenalty=9999 
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand*{\Quote}[1]{\textquotedblleft#1\textquotedblright}

\def\Hanh{H\`an Th\^e\llap{\raise 0.5ex\hbox{\'{}}} Th\`anh}

\ifpdf
  \usepackage[%
    pdftex,%
    colorlinks,%
    hyperindex,%
    plainpages=false,%
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    a4paper,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=blue,
  ]{hyperref}
  %%?? \def\pdfBorderAttrs{/Border [0 0 0] } % No border arround Links
  \usepackage{thumbpdf}
\else
  \usepackage{hyperref}
\fi

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\thepage} 
%\lhead[\fancyplain{}{}]
%      {\fancyplain{}{}}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%  %Make the Chapter title in low case
%\markboth{\chaptername
%\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % This removes the line added by Fancy header

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Beginning of Document - First Page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image.png}}

{\huge \textbf{Investigating the impact of flavonoid compounds on the cGAS-STING pathway}\par}

\vspace{1cm}

\textbf{XXX}\\ Student ID: 6789976\\Jan 2018-December 2021


\vspace{2cm}

A thesis submitted for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy \\at XXX University\\

Research was carried out\\in the ABCD\\ affiliated with XXX\\
Under the supervision of \\
A/Prof ASD (75\%)\\
and ASC(25\%)
 \end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any alternative to not have the title in a floating environment? I need to add a logo at the title page, which is why is used " \begin{figure} and \end{figure}". Also, Is there any way to add indent before a paragraph? Lyx usually does this along with alignment-but as I mentioned, those specific pages are not aligned and there is no indention before the starting paragraphs. Adding a blank line does not indicate lyx to begin a new paragraph, so I am trying using \phantom{this text is invisible} before a new paragraph followed by a "\\"> Are there any better ways?

Comment: just delete the begin figure and end figure lines they are doing nothing useful you do not need them to use `\includegraphics`Oh but they do set paragraph indent to 0pt which is probably your issue.

Comment: nothing is solved, it rather splitted the image, title, author name and university names in separate pages, and the alignment is still now justified..I am clueless at this stage. please help

Comment: @TomalikaUllah I added something to my answer